# In the process of constructing a highway across a certain region in which there are many hills and valleys

Tags: calculus

In the process of constructing a highway across a certain region in which there are many hills and valleys. the engineer will be certain that

There is some level in between the elevations of the highest hill and the
lowest valley at which the surface of the highway can be laid using the
tops of the hills as fill material for the valleys and such that no
additional fill dirt need be brought in from another region and none will be left to be hauled away.

To build a mathematical model of this situation. let S be a long. narrow rectangular
region (the roadbed) bounded by the lines At x = a. x = b, y = c. and y = d; let f
be a continuous function on S with M and m being, respectively, the maximum and
minimum values of f on S. If the graph of f is identified with the surface of the
land, then, of the following. Which best corresponds to the assertion set off in braces
above?

(A) There exists a point p in S such that m $ \leq $ f (p) $ \leq $ M.

(B) There exists a value q off such that M - m = q.

(C) There exists a point p in S such that $\iint_{S} f = f(p) $ . (area of S).

(D)$\int_{a}^{b} \left(\int_{c}^{d} f\left(x,y\right)   \right) dx =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  \bigg\rvert_{(a,b)} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \bigg\rvert_{(c,d)}$

(E) There exists a value of such that q of f such that $ \frac{q}{(area \, of \,  S)} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  \bigg\rvert_{(a,b)} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \bigg\rvert_{(c,d)}$

I am confused with this question how should one approch it and why answer (C) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Answer (C) is correct and it is the mean value property for continuous functions.

Namely, your problem asks to build a parallelepiped with base $S$ and a certain heigth $h$ such that its volume $h\cdot |S|$ (with $|S| = $ area of $S$) coincides with the total volume of your landscape, given by $\iint_S f$, so that
$h$ must satisfy
$$
h = \mu_f := \frac{1}{|S|} \iint_S f.
$$

On the other hand, you see in a moment that, since $m\leq f \leq M$, then $m\leq \mu_f \leq M$. 
Hence, by the continuity of $f$ there is a point $p\in S$ such that $f(p) = \mu_f$, i.e. (C) follows.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that answer (C) is nearest to the content of the story. But even closer would come

(F)$\quad$ There is a number $\ell$ such that ${\displaystyle \ \int_S f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\ell\cdot{\rm area}(S)}\ $.

Note that the text talks about a "level", and not about a particular point $p$. In fact, the function $f$ need not be continuous in order to be feasible for the engineer's task; *integrability* is sufficient. Imagine a mesa like cliff through which the horizontal road will pass. The critical level $\ell$ could just be at half the height off the cliff; hence there is no point $p$ of the kind mentioned in (C).